# Calculate checksum (XOR) of sentence ( formed by combination of different variables/types )

Tags: c++, arduino, checksum

How do I calculate the checksum of a sentence?

```
// Calculate checksum of characters between $ and *, not including & and *
$HMTV,13534,-58,50:65,00,0F,40,*
```

The checksum, I know is the representation of two hexadecimal characters of an XOR of all characters ( but not including the $ and the * character ). The above sentence is generated by the snippet shown below. I want to add a checksum ( after the * ) so that I can validate the sentence on the other side which receives it. This data is sent out by Serial.printf ( unless there's a better way? )

Here's the code that generates the sentence shown above

```
void setup() 
{
  char devid[6];
  char bledata[9];
  char scantimestamp[16]; // ( the source is int32_t )
  char rssilevel[11]; // (the source is int8_t )

      snprintf(devid, 6, "%02X:%02X",  
          records[i].addr[1],
          records[i].addr[0]
      );
      snprintf(bledata, 9, "%02X,%02X,%02X",  
          records[i].advData[2],
          records[i].advData[1],
          records[i].advData[0]
      );
      sprintf(scantimestamp,"%lu", records[i].timestamp);
      sprintf(rssilevel, "%d", records[i].rssi);          
      Serial.printf("%s,%u,%i,%s,%s\n", "$HMTV", records[i].timestamp, records[i].rssi, devid, bledata);
}
```

The checksum for the above sentence ( by XOR ) should be 75. So I'd want to add it to the end of the sentence to make it like this

```
$HMTV,13534,-58,50:65,00,0F,40,*75
```

and send it out so that I can validate the checksum on the other side. I only have about 2 days of experience programming on a Arduino(c++) so I am not sure what would be the optimal way as I need it to be efficient ( as many sentences get processed in short intervals of time ). For me the thing that has complicated the matter is that the sentence is formed by a combination of different data types and I am nowhere near a pro to get this right on this occasion. Thank you so much. Love ya'll, you guys are darn cool at what you do! :)

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Be [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Comment: The output of this (      Serial.printf("%s,%u,%i,%s,%s\n", "$HMTV", records[i].timestamp, records[i].rssi, devid, bledata);
) I want it to go to an (single) array or a buffer so that I can calculate the checksum by looping or something. Otw I have to loop through all the individual buffers and then do the XOR on those.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend debugging Arduino programs on the PC as much as possible before trying out on the Arduino.

That said,

1) Read the text into `std::string` variable:

```
std::string text;
std::getline(cin, text);
```

2) Loop through the string, processing each character:

```
uint8_t checksum = 0;
unsigned int index = 1; // Skip $ character at beginning
const unsigned int length = text.length();
for (; (index < length); ++index)
{
  const char c = text[index];
  if (c == '*')
    break;
  checksum = checksum ^ c;
}
```

The remaining part is to output the data and the `checksum`, which is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: hi Thomas, yes, everything I can I am trying to debug on the PC itself. Thanks for the snippet, let me try it. Appreciate your kind help. Cheers